# How to make dashed lines with drawMatches on OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I am drawing matches between keypoints in two images. I need the lines that are made with cv2.drawMatches to be dashed. I have not been able to make that happen. This is how I am making the lines:

```
# Draw matches again
matched_images = cv2.drawMatches(
    img1,
    kps1,
    img2,
    kps2,
    matches_dmatch,
    None,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible with `drawMatches`.

The documentation mentions no "dash" or "dot" styles: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d5d/group__features2d__draw.html

If you need that, you'll have to do the drawing yourself. OpenCV's other drawing functions don't support dashed/dotted style either.

If you were using C++, you could use `cv::LineIterator` and paint or not paint individual pixels along a line.

In python, you'd have to use the "Bresenham" algorithm for lines... you can probably find that implemented somewhere already, or you can implement it yourself.

you don't need to use the Bresenham algorithm either. you could just calculate the start and end point of every dash, and issue a `cv.line()` call for each.